# Microsoft Graph - Create outlook/teams meeting as a application .Net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create a meeting as a application, add attendees, determine time availability.

This is what I have so far :

**Auth**

```
private async Task<ClientCredentialProvider> GetToken()
{
    var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(_microsoftAppId)
        .WithTenantId(_microsoftTenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(_microsoftAppPassword)
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
    return authProvider;
}
```

**Meeting request**

```
public async Task GetMeetingtime()
{
    var authProvider = await GetToken();
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    var attendees = new List<AttendeeBase>()
    {
        new AttendeeBase
        {
            Type = AttendeeType.Required,
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Name = "john doe",
                Address = "john.doe@onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        },

        new AttendeeBase
        {
            Type = AttendeeType.Required,
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Name = "john toe",
                Address = "john.toe@onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    };


    var locationConstraint = new LocationConstraint
    {
        IsRequired = false,
        SuggestLocation = false,
        Locations = new List<LocationConstraintItem>()
        {
            new LocationConstraintItem
            {
                ResolveAvailability = false,
                DisplayName = "Conf room Hood"
            }
        }
    };


    var timeConstraint = new TimeConstraint
    {
        ActivityDomain = ActivityDomain.Work,
        TimeSlots = new List<TimeSlot>()
        {
            new TimeSlot
            {
                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2020-12-10T09:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                },
                End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2020-12-10T17:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var isOrganizerOptional = false;

    var meetingDuration = new Duration("PT1H");

    var returnSuggestionReasons = true;

    var minimumAttendeePercentage = (double)100;

    await graphClient
        .Me
        .FindMeetingTimes(attendees, locationConstraint, timeConstraint, meetingDuration, null, isOrganizerOptional, returnSuggestionReasons, minimumAttendeePercentage)
        .Request()
        .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"Pacific Standard Time\"")
        .PostAsync();
}
```

This is the error I get:

`Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well, this part surely will not work: `.Me`. "me" is an alias for `/users/current-user-id` in MS Graph. Since you don't have a current user, it doesn't work. I'll go have a look in the MS Graph docs if this is possible as an app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs, the findMeetingTimes API does not support application-only access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
It can only be called in the context of a signed-in user.
Now, you could try to use `.Users["user-id"]` instead of `.Me` just in case the docs are wrong about this.
"me" only makes sense when calling the API on behalf of a user, which you are not.

Calendar events can be created as an application that has write access to the users' calendars.

Comment: Hello and thank for your answer. I've tried to use .Users["something"] , but really I don't know how do I get a `user-id`, also can it be any user-id? Can you provide an example?

Comment: It's usually the objectId of the user. You can get those through the /users API or from Azure Portal user properties.

Comment: I've managed to get my `user-id`. But I'm getting this error `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`

Comment: It is possible then that the scenario is simply not supported when using an application with no signed in user.